# How to convert Java JSpinner number to int ?

Tags: java, swing, numbers, integer, jspinner

In Java, I've been trying to cast a JSpinner number input to an integer using Netbeans. I've made it so that the JSpinner input is a number, but I can't try to cast it to my own integer without receiving errors. I've tried many various things and one of the errors I most commonly receive is "Inconvertible types, required int, found JSpinner." How would I just simply be able to assign a JSpinner input (preferably a number) to an integer.

Comment: *"I've tried many various things"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the one you think is closest to working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't cast the spinner itself to a number. You need to get its value. You can use:

```
((SpinnerNumberModel) spinner.getModel())).getNumber().intValue()
```

This will only work if the underlying model is a `SpinnerNumberModel` (default). You could also use:

```
Object o = spinner.getValue();
Number n = (Number) o;
int i = n.intValue();
```

This will work as long as the value can be cast to a `Number`.

Comment: @Mel yes, true; this is example code, not production code. In reality I'd keep a reference to the original model.